# Spring Boot code not working when called from browser using http://localhost/test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

**controller class:**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController  
public class HelloWorldController   
{  
    //using get method and hello-world as URI  
    // @GetMapping(path="/hello-world-bean")  
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/test")  
    public String sayHello()  
    {  
        return "Hello !!!";  
    }  
        
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getSquare/{number}")
    public int getSquareOfNumber(@PathVariable int number)
    {
        return number*number;
        
    }
}
```

**Application class:**

```
package com.firstService.server.main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestfulWebServicesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestfulWebServicesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I am trying to call url **http://localhost/test** (I am displaying Hello for url /hello), it is not getting called and showing me below error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using dependency `spring-boot-starter-web` or `spring-webmvc`? Also, add `scanBasePackages = "com.firstService"` to your SpringBootApplication annotation so @RestController is picked up as a bean (unless it also resides in package `com.firstService.server.main` ?)

Comment: spring-boot-starter-web This dependency was missing in pom.xml. Thanks Nico !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spring-boot-starter-web This dependency was missing in pom.xml. Thanks Nico !

I have added below dependency in pom.xml and url is changed to http://localhost:8080/hello

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Let me upvote my own answer :D lol

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with explicitly adding port also on which your application is running like
http://localhost:8080/test

Comment: I have tried this. Actually I have another server running at port 8080. So I dont what exact url I need to call to get webservice called.

Comment: Is this application started properly? You can check through console logs. If it is started without any error, then on which port it is running? use that port to access the url then.

Comment: By default a Spring Boot applocation will start at port 8080, unless you have added a configuration on your `application.properties` something like: `server.port=xxxx, have you tried this? You can see more details here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-port